# Installing Python Imaging Library on my iPhone's Python interpreter

Tags: iphone, python

I've been learning python for some time now. Recently I needed to install in my Mac the Image module for Python, and after a while I achieve this running a mpkg installer specially for my OS, so far everything was ok and I could run my script.

Now I'm in the needing of running my script in my jailbroken iPhone, which already has a python interpreter, and I need to install this Image module again but this time on my phone.

Is there another way to do it? How can I do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how

I downloaded the PIL 1.1.7 source from http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ and untared the Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz file, then I made the following commands:

```
cd Imaging-1.1.7/
python setup.py install
```

You can also follow the instructions on the README file in Imaging-1.1.7/ for building the package on your own.

that's it

Comment: I get this error: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 191, in _find_appropriate_compiler
    "Cannot locate working compiler")
SystemError: Cannot locate working compiler

Comment: Probably you have a brand new mac. You need to install dev tools that comes with xcode and command line utilities. Once you do it try again.

Comment: It's not a Mac. It's a jailbroken iPhone as the original post declares.

Comment: Try again after being sure to have C/C++ compilers installed, once you do it, the installation of PIL will advance forward but you will likely face some other errors ahead due to some dev-libs missing. Continue by installing them one by one, hopefully there will be architecture compatible versions available with your phone (I tried it like 6-7 years ago, the processors have changed since), be sure to choose the appropriate ones. Happy hacking.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to advance after installing "iOS Toolchain" from Cydia but ran into dependency problems with zlib (which I got around) but ultimately faced a brick wall with libtiff as it won't accept my supplied one and I don't have, nor can I compile, the necessary one. I am leaving this comment in the hope that someone could help me find/add them. Is there a place/repo where I can install these pre-requisites from? I am at a loss on how to fulfill them.